# How to prevent CKEditor from removing content and tags written in source?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I'd like to be able to use things such as the  *tag for purposes of using font awesome icons, but CKEditor strips tags like this. If I place* 
 when in 'source' mode in ckeditor it gets removed as soon as I return to the standard mode. Is there a way to ensure that ckeditor allows these tags?

I saw that someone provided a solution here [How to stop CKEditor 3.6.3.7474 from stripping <script> tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40235/how-to-stop-ckeditor-3-6-3-7474-from-stripping-script-tags) however in drupal 8 admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/advanced does not exist.

I also saw the CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21src%21CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface.php/interface/CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface/8.2.x
But I wasn't sure how to make use of that.

Is there a way to prevent CKEditor from removing content and tags written in 'source'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are using Full HTML format it should work fine, e.g. this works no problem:

```
<a href="https://www.drupal.org/"><i class="fa fa-drupal">&zwnj;</i> Drupal.org</a>
```

This uses the zero-width non-joiner character instead of a non-breaking-space (makes little difference).

Note you won't see the icon in the CKEditor unless you load Font Awesome into the editorSettings contentsCss.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement, I followed this tutorial for that, [How to Display Icons in Drupal using Icon API](https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/how-display-icons-drupal-using-icon-api).

It needs two modules (1) [Fontawesome](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) and its dependencies [Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module & [Fontawesome Library](http://fontawesome.io/). (2) Other module you need is [Icon API](https://www.drupal.org/project/icon) which has sub-module Icon_filter that will convert the icons in the images.

I am afraid that Icon API module will work for D8 or not, but it has D8 version but unstable as you can see on the module page.

I am using this way on D7 site.

**Update:** Filter setting

[image]

Comment: I already have the Fontawesome library included as part of my theme. is there a way I can just get ckeditor to respect me adding a tag without me having to install more redundant modules?

Comment: I am not sure How will you display Fontawesome icon without the Font-awesome module. If there is a way that using just Font-awesome  library, I am not aware. I think fontawesome module in Drupal has been created for displaying Fontawesome icons Otherwise why module was created.

Comment: I'm already able to display fontawesome icons on any page. Font awesome is already included in my theme.libraries.yml file. The only difference is that inside of ckeditor empty <i> tags are removed. Font awesome isn't really the issue. Even if I don't care about font awesome certain html tags are still removed, which is a behavior I don't want.

Comment: Are you using the Full HTML text format? Try to use Full format and add the fontawesome like `<i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;</i>`, It will not strip off this.

Comment: The textformat is set to 'Full HTML' yes.

Comment: I am not sure why it is stripping off, In my D8 trial site if i add it just gets embedded in `<p></p>` like  `<p><i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;</i></p>`, but Ckeditor is not stripping off. Just I am posting image of my Full text filter, may it help.

Answer (score -1):

CKeditor has Content Filtering.

> Configure input data filtering in CKEditor. See this [blog post](https://ckeditor.com/blog/Upgrading-to-CKEditor-4.1/) for more information about ACF.

By the way, there are two solutions to avoid CKEditor filters content. An easy solution is to disable *Advanced Filtering Feature* on admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full, but I don't recommend it in all cases. A better solution is settings your tags on admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (*Extra allowed content*).

> [image: Exclude script tags from filtering in CKeditor]